# PHP regexp match slash

Tags: php, regex

I have the following regular expression tested at [regex101](http://www.regex101.com/) and it works there. However, when I try to use it inside the preg_match it doesn't work anymore. The problem is the slash: I tried escaping it but I can't get it working.

```
preg_match("/[<>\\\"'%;()&]/", "my\string");
```

The set of characters that I should match are:

```
< > \ " ' % ; ( ) &
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply use a different delimiter:

```
preg_match("![<>\\\"'%;()&/]!", "my\string");
```

Comment: thank you but what if I want to use the / as delimiter? I found that using 4 slashes to match a single \ works but I can't understand why I need that amount of characters

Comment: What is the point in using `/`  as delimiter, if you want to use it as character? `\` is a different question: First, you need to escape the backslash in the regular expression (-> 2 backslashes), then these two backslashes in PHP (-> 4 backslashes)